# Prove the limit of a function approach to a derivative

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, limits-without-lhopital

So here is the question:

Suppose that $f:(-1,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at $0$ and that $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ are sequences in $(-1,1)$ such that $x_n\to 0, y_n \to 0$, and $x_n < y_n$ for all $n$. Let $$D_n = \frac{f(y_n)-f(x_n)}{y_n - x_n}$$

Show that if $f'$ is defined and continuous in $(-1,1)$ then $D_n \to f'(0)$

I've thought to prove this by holding $x_n$ fixed and take $y_n\to0$, then take $x_n\to0$.
But I then have a concern that the limit by taking $x_n\to0,y_n\to0$ separately may not be equal to the limit by taking $x_n\to0,y_n\to0$ at the same time.

Is there another approach for this?
Or is there any evidence to show that the limits by taking $x_n,y_n\to0$ separately or at the same time are the same?

Comment: Try [the mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem).

Comment: The result is true without continuity of $f'$ but then we must have $x_n<0<y_n$ or $x_n>0>y_n$.

Comment: Oh, I think that'll work, since $x_n < y_n$ for all $n$ so we can take a sequences of intervals that goes to 0

Comment: Paramanand, yes, that's the first part of problem, and I got that part, this is the third and I'm stuck

Comment: If the limits $y_n/(y_n-x_n)$ and $x_n/(y_n-x_n)$ exist, you only need that $f'(0)$ exists...

Comment: ^^That's the second part of the problem, and I got that part as well. Thanks for the hint though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

By mean value theorem, for every $n$ there exists a $c_n\in(x_n,y_n)$ with
$$ D_n = \frac{f(y_n) - f(x_n)}{y_n - x_n} = f'(c_n).$$
Now, as $y_n - x_n \to 0$ it follows $c_n \to 0$ and $D_n\to...?$